# Isn't ASP.NET MVC actually MCVMV?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm

Setting up an application using ASP.NET MVC I wondered if the term "MVC" actually covers the application framework. I thought about WPF and MVVM wich clearly states the use of a ViewModel which MVC does not. By using:

- A Domain model (entities)
- Controllers
- ViewModels and
- Views

I think **M**(odel) **C**(ontroller) **VM**(ViewModel) **V**(iew) **MCVMV** is a more accurate description of the framework. Although I believe some people skip the use of a ViewModel which I actually find very usefull. What are your considerations about this?

Comment: "I would like to discuss.." - might be more suited to [programmers](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), although the question wording should be cleaned up to elicit more direct responses, if possible.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is just another Rails clone. It has nothing to do with MVC or MVVM. They are just abusing the names.

Comment: @tereško that's not correct.  They are using the MVC pattern.  And a lot of Rail's convention-based application design, yeah.  But it's not an abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question will undoubtedly be closed, but it's best to look at it as a loose approximation. All of the patterns; MVC, MVVM, etc.; are guidelines, and frameworks merely follow them to a greater or lesser degree. ASP.NET MVC is called such because it mostly follows an MVC track. The model in ASP.NET MVC is particularly loose, as what is called a model is typically just an Entity Framework *entity*, a very poor excuse for a true MVC model. View Models have been co-opted from MVVM largely to compensate for this. For comparison, look at the model in something like Ruby on Rails. Not only is it the database backed entity, but it's also the repository for that entity, holds all the validation logic for both the database and views, etc. There's just really nothing close to the same thing in ASP.NET MVC. Long and short, yes, ASP.NET MVC typically incorporates a View Model as well, but the last thing we need is another acronym.

Comment: I hope you are aware that "viewmodel" would be replacing the controller for MVVM. What .NET calls "viewmodel" are actually poorly made bastardization of [presentation objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

Comment: Well, yes and no. In MVVM you don't really have a controller. You have some sort of routing infrastructure typically, and then the view model which acts as controller, per se, but it's really such a different concept from the controller of MVC, that you can't compare the two. If you had to, the VM of MVVM is like the bastard love child of the controller and model of MVC; with traits of each, but not really fully either one.

Comment: Thanx for the answer and comments. They made my understanding of those frameworks a bit "deeper".